# PHP performance: Class passed as argument VS new creating instance

Tags: php, performance

Since I don't understand many under-the-hood mechanics of PHP, I am looking for someone, who could explain to me, what exactly happens, when a class is passed as an argument to a function and whether it's faster than creating a new instance of the class inside the function.

```
function test($some_big_class) {

    print($some_big_class->some_text);

}
```

VS

```
function test() {

    $some_big_class = new Some_Big_class();
    print($some_big_class->some_text);

}
```

Which one would be faster? 
Which one would consume less space?
Is the first option a bad idea ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: There's virtually no difference in speed here, but a giant difference in meaning. Do you want to pass an instance in, or instantiate a new instance? Performance is the least of your worries here, what you're trying to do is the main thing.

Comment: Class? You probably mean *instance of a class*.